# Regex on binary data in python 3.6 shows weird behaviour

Tags: regex, python-3.x, binary-data

I'm trying to write a small script that reads binary data from a file before processing it further, with e.g. regex for simplifying some steps.

During the regex I'm seeing some weird behavior I just can't figure out of. Code basically goes like this (heavily stripped down to just include the relevant part):

```
fh = open(filename,'rb')
bd = fh.read(32) # binary data
xlen = bd[3] # byte that specifies length of a command - this may vary for each 32h byte read
bd_x = bd[4:4+xlen] # pick out interesting part of the data. for the data I see the weird behavior the length of bd_x will always be 7
if re.match(b'\x00((.*?){%d})\x30'%(xlen-2),bd_x):
    update some other lists, etc
```

Just need to check if start of interesting data is `\x00` and if end is `\x30` with 5 other elements in between, for which value is irrelevant. Total length, including start and end I'm trying to match is thus 7, as mentioned.

In a sample file I have with random data, this works on about 100 of 130 32h byte chunks, for which it should match on all 130 and not just 100.

I did print out out the content of `bd_x` for both cases, e.g. for chunks where it worked and chunks where it didn't. Output from `print(xlen,hexlify(bd_x))` (n for negative, p for positive).

```
n 7 b'000000290a0030'
n 7 b'0000002b0a0030'
n 7 b'0000002d0a0030'
n 7 b'0000002f0a0030'
n 7 b'000000310a0030'
n 7 b'000000330a0030'
p 7 b'00000003000030'
p 7 b'00000005000030'
p 7 b'00000000000030'
p 7 b'00000000020030'
```

As far as I can see, all samples should have matched in the regex. If I change to `re.search` it matches on all 130 chunks, but tbh I don't know why `re.match` isn't working for all chunks of data as the start always matches with `\x00` and the rest should match too.

I've manually checked all the entries of the test file that fail in a hex-editor, and I just can't see why it doesn't work on those entries.

I know I can probably just do `hexlify(bd_x)` and just operate on the output from that function instead, but for now I'm interested in figuring out why this doesn't work.

Suggestions / solutions are appreciated.

Comment: The failing samples all contain newline characters (0x0A), which are NOT matched by `.` in a regex unless you specify the `DOTALL` flag.  `re.search()` works because it's actually matching only the `0030` at the end.

Comment: Arg, that never occured to me, thanks a lot for pointing it out! Added ``DOTALL`` and it all works as it should. If you can post it as an answer I'll accept it so the question can be closed.

Comment: Also, if anyone should have a suggestion to improve/speed up the matching in the re-pattern it'd be great. I see that (.*?) gets quite slow compared to other matches, but for some reason I can't get ([0-9a-fA-F]{m}) to work properly, so not sure what I'm missing when trying options like that.

Comment: `[0-9a-fA-F]{m}` would only match the hexlified version of the data, not the data itself.  You just want `.{m}` to match a given length of bytes.  But I'm not sure regex is even the right tool here: `bd[4] == '\x00' and bd[3+xlen] == '\x30'` seems to express the same test.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I have a version of the function I'm using for the filtering where I have used if-else statements which of course is way faster, but I thought I could sacrifice some speed to make it a bit more compact, but the (.*?) approach is a bit too slow, so will most likely end up with the if-else one, but wanted to ask if there maybe was something in between what I had tried and what I already have. Anyways, thanks.